# should homebrew services run as root?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm running some standard services using homebrew on a macbook pro running `Sierra`.

```
➜  ~ brew services list
Name       Status  User     Plist
dnsmasq    started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb    started [myuser] /Users/[myuser]/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx      started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php70      started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist
```

Note that most of these are running as `root` except for `mariadb`. Is this normal, or did I mess up something when installing these services (possibly `sudo`'ing when I shouldn't have?)

If this is incorrect can anyone recommend the best way to fix it?

Comment: I think this should be moved to the [Ask Different stackexchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @jerry-- it's worth a shot-- however, this is a programming box, there's both `osx` and `homebrew` tags on SO, and most of AskDifferent deals with basic mac use and hardware questions more than specific software issues.

Comment: I don't disagree that questions involving Homebrew or OS X can be on-topic here, but they have to be focused on programming. I hope you don't take offense, but I think this type of question about the basic setup and use of a package manager (whether it be Homebrew, apt-get, or any other) doesn't meet that criterion. As for Ask Different, I think you may be surprised. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150271/how-to-repair-homebrew-permissions-after-installing-as-root], for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct, and shouldn't have used `sudo` to install them. Homebrew should give you a warning for even trying, and I don't think it will even allow you to install or update with `sudo`.  I know that's what it's done for me.